# How to override a class that the parent imports from the child in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a child class that extends a parent. The parent imports a class that I would like to override in the child. Is this possible?

Code structure like so:

Parent:

```
import {TestClass} from './TestClass';
export class Parent {
  /** etc **/
}
```

Child:

```
import {Parent} from './Parent';
export class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  //how to import/override TestClass from Parent?
}
```

Comment: You can't, you'd have to override the *methods* that refer to `TestClass`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `Parent` doesn't actually extend `TestClass`, but if it did you would be able to override methods from `Parent` and `TestClass` from within the `Child` class - shortened example:

```
class TestClass {
    methodOne() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class Parent extends TestClass {
    methodTwo() {
        return this.methodOne() + 1;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    methodOne() {
        return 11;
    }
}

var x = new Child();

// 11 (rather than 1)
alert(x.methodOne());

// 12 (rather than 2)
alert(x.methodTwo());
```

Note how the method on parent, which calls the `methodOne` method, returns the value based on the child `methodOne`, not the test class `methodOne`.